# Implicitly pass the "this" OR the "type" of the calling class to a non-member template function

Tags: c++, c++17, template-argument-deduction, function-templates

is there a way to implicitly pass the `this` of the calling class to a template function being called?

i tried the following so far:

```
template<class P, class T>
void funcA(P& p, T const* t = this){   //<--does not work.
    //...some code here...
}

class TypeX { }

class TypeA {
public: 
    void DoSomething(){
        TypeX x;
        funcA(x, this);   //compiles fine
        //funcA(x);       //<---my goal: implicitly pass "this" by default.

    }
}

void main(){
    
    TypeA objX;
    
    objX.DoSomething();
    
}
```

for the `type-of-"this"` problem, i had the following working so far:

```
template<class T, class P>
constexpr auto funcA(P& p) {
    //...some code here that also uses type T...
}

class TypeA {
    public: 
        void DoSomething(){
            TypeX x;
            funcA<TypeA>(x);   //<---explicitly passing TypeA. (compiles)
            //funcA(x);        //<---my goal.
            //funcA<>(x);      //<---my goal(fair enough)
        }
    }
}
```

as you can see, i explicitly pass the `TypeA` to `funcA`. looks like redundant to me. though it's currently running fine in my project, i tried making it cleaner by making `funcA<TypeA>(x)` to `funcA(x)`. but no success so far. i'm hoping it's still possible to do this so i asked here in SO.

Comment: make `funcA` a member function

Comment: As long as `funcA` is not a member function of `TypeA` then it's not possible. What is the problem that's supposed to solve? Why do you need this?

Comment: @StefanRiedel `funcA` must be a non-member of a class, specially the target class it will be called.

Comment: I don't know for sure what you mean by "specially the target class it will be called", but as Some programmer dude said, it's not possible otherwise. It looks like you want to have a base class `TypeX` and `TypeA` inherit from that has a member template function `template<typename P> void funcA(...)`

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude originally, the problem is: getting the `type` of the calling class be known inside the function-template without explicitly passing that `type`. and then later on i needed also implicitly passing `this`. and then i asked this question first. is there a way/solution for my original problem?

Comment: @StefanRiedel i mean, "target-class" is the class where the `funcA(...)` will be called. i guess it can be possible that `funcA` can be a member of some-other-class but should not be a member of `TypeA`. i'm actually making a utility function.

Comment: Basically what you're saying is "I want to pass the type and `this` because I want to pass the type and `this`". There must be an underlying reason you want to pass the type and `this`. That makes this question [an XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Always ask directly about the underlying problem you try to solve with the solution you need help with. There might be other solutions you haven't thought about.

Comment: My beard is grey enough for `#define FUNCA(x) funcA(x, this)`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude sorry if it's vague. i actually solved the specific problem i had. the currently solutions are "explicitly" pass the `this` or the `decltype(this)`. but i'm curious if it's possible to make it "implicit". that would be better for me since i can get rid of keywords that, IMO, "seems" redundant. the lesser the params the better. i tried different way and then i gave up and then ask experts online.

Comment: @molbdnilo i might choose this approach someday. ;)) macros are underrated sometimes. for now, i'm looking for a no-macro solution. :)

Answer (score 2):

In a comment, you said,

> `funcA` must be a non-member of a class, specially the target class it will be called.

Given that, it's not possible to use `this` as the default value of an argument of the function.

---

I don't see any problem with the following:

```
template<class P, class T>
void funcA(P& p, T const* t){
    //...some code here...
}

class TypeX { };

class TypeA {
public: 
    void DoSomething(){
        TypeX x;
        funcA(x, this);   // Explicitly pass "this".
    }
};
```

It is not onerous either.

Comment: yes, this is what i did also(for now). i want to know if there are already possible tricks to get "this" or its type without explicitly passing it.

Comment: @acegs, the answer is a definite "no" to implicitly passing `this`. The type is deduced from the argument used to make the call.